# What home insurance policy riders does the average person buy?

Tags: insurance, home-ownership, home-insurance

While researching home insurance policies I found myself wondering how often other home owners purchase certain policy riders, such as water backup and sump overflow protection. Are there any resources, surveys, etc that have ascertained what the average home owner adds to their insurance policy?

Answer (score 1):

What do you have that your normal coverage wouldn't let you replace but that you can't afford to do without? What liabilities do you need additional protection from? If you don't know what you are guarding against, you probably don't need protection from it. In my case, I have my home and auto insurance under an umbrella to increase them above common levels, plus a rider on one piece of property that really is not easily replaced.